# How to use articles in parentheses?

Tags: articles, parentheses

Do I need to use an article for the option word in parentheses?

> If you want to create a new design of a handle (flag), the outer
>   diameter of the casing can be changed in the place of possible
>   junction with a handle (diverter).

or

> If you want to create a new design of a handle (*a* flag), the outer
>   diameter of the casing can be changed in the place of possible
>   junction with a handle (*a* diverter).

or even

> If you want to create a new design of a handle (or flag), the outer
>   diameter of the casing can be changed in the place of possible
>   junction with a handle (or diverter).

Answer (score 1):

Parentheticals are used for various different purposes. I'd read the different versions above thus:

> If you want to create a new design of a handle (flag), ...

'flag' is being given as a synonym for 'handle'; the construction is appositive.

> If you want to create a new design of a handle (a flag), ...

'flag' is being given as a relevant subset of 'handle'; the parenthetical is adding more information.

> If you want to create a new design of a handle (or flag), ...

the possibility of creating a new type of flag is being introduced, as an alternative to creating a new design of handle. The parenthetical is adding a further possibility to consider.

Of course, here, the first option is probably the one intended.

Comment: Yes, "as an alternative". Should I use the article in this case (without 'or')?

Comment: To make it absolutely clear, I'd use (also known as a 'flag') or (called a 'flag' in the industry) or the like. Conciseness is good, but clarity is better.